# rails integration test logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, integration-testing

Is there any way to see what is happening during an integration test?

When I test my application manually, I can look at the webserver logs to see what parameters are sent, which queries are run and can use `puts` to log variables. Is there any way to do this during an integration test? I found `/log/test.log` but it doesn't show much.

Thanks
Walter

Comment: `test.log` should include all of your key events (page renders, database updates, etc).  If you don't see that, there may be a problem with your test set up or the test itself.  Also, if you are running mini test, you should be able to add a line like `assert_equal body, 'foo'` to dump the current page to the screen (and stop the test) as a quick debug mechanism.  See documentation on integration testing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this in your test file to mimic a console.log of a javascript program. It's output will be available in log/test.log

```
Rails::logger.debug "The value of x at this time is " + x
```